# In Chef, how do I access attributes set in the environment JSON from cookbook attributes files?

Tags: chef, attributes

I have a chef system where we have multiple environments and have attributes set in evironment JSON.

I'm having trouble accessing these from within cookbook attribute files and recipes.

Answer (score 2):

What does your environment file look like? Are you setting default or override attributes? If you're setting default, note that is a fairly low priority level in the attributes chain, so it might be overridden by a recipe, or a role.

The precedence of the attributes is as follows, from low to high:

1. default attributes applied in an attributes file
2. default attributes applied in an environment
3. default attributes applied in a role
4. default attributes applied on a node directly in a recipe
5. normal or set attributes applied in an attributes file
6. normal or set attributes applied on a node directly in a recipe
7. override attributes applied in an attributes file
8. override attributes applied in a role
9. override attributes applied in an environment
10. override attributes applied on a node directly in a recipe

Above from:

- http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Attributes

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to use environment's attribute in the Chef recipe.
Lets say we have an environment like this:

```
{
  "name": "QA",
  "description": "QA environment",
  "cookbook_versions": {
  },
  "json_class": "Chef::Environment",
  "chef_type": "environment",
  "default_attributes": {
    "comp_rsyslog": {
      "filetag_env": "compqa"
    }
  },
  "override_attributes": {
  }
}
```

And we need to use the filetag_env attribute in the service's template config file to pass the environment attribute.

The way I do in the conf erb file it's like:

```
$InputFileTag <%= node['comp_rsyslog']['filetag_env'] %>,<%= node['rsyslog']['filetag1'] %>
```

The `<%= node['rsyslog']['filetag1'] %>` is defined in the recipe attribute's file:

```
default['rsyslog']['filetag1'] = 'comp_service'
```

The result will be a file in `/etc/rsyslog.d/comp_service.conf` with a content like:

```
$InputFileTag compqa,comp_service.
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct order is now, as taken [from the chef documentation site](http://docs.chef.io/nodes.html#attributes):

1. A default attribute located in a cookbook attribute file
2. A default attribute located in a recipe
3. A default attribute located in an environment
4. A default attribute located in role
5. A force_default attribute located in a cookbook attribute file
6. A force_default attribute located in a recipe
7. A normal attribute located in a cookbook attribute file
8. A normal attribute located in a recipe
9. An override attribute located in a cookbook attribute file
10. An override attribute located in a recipe
11. An override attribute located in a role
12. An override attribute located in an environment
13. A force_override attribute located in a cookbook attribute file
14. A force_override attribute located in a recipe
15. An automatic attribute identified by Ohai at the start of the chef-client run

Comment: Note that you can also blacklist or whitelist attributes, which serves to make Chef one of the most convoluted configuration management tools I've ever used. https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence